# an option can chosen from a dropdown list which lead to another dropdown list with only items based on first selection in html5

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {
            var value1 = $('#first').val();
            var value2 = $('#second').val();
            $("select.chance").change(function(){
                var value3=$(".chance option:selected").val();
            });
            $('input[name="item_meta[rd1][]"],input[name="item_meta[rd2][]"]').change(function(){
        var value4 = $("input[name='item_meta[rd1][]']:checked").length;
             return this.value();
                var value4=$("input[name='item_meta[rd1][]']:checked").length;
                return this.value();
         });
         $('input[name="item_meta[ch1][]"]').change(function(){
        var value5 = $("input[name='item_meta[ch1][]']:checked").length;
             return this.value();
         });
        $('input[name="item_meta[ch2][]"]').change(function(){
        var value6 = $("input[name='item_meta[ch2][]']:checked").length;
             return this.value();
        });
             var sum = parseInt(value1, 10) + parseInt(value2, 10) + parseInt(value3, 10) + parseInt(value4, 10) + parseInt(value5, 10) + parseInt(value6, 10);
            $('#msg').html(sum);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Html**
 
            
                totalmark
                
            
            
                second mrk
                
            
            
                No of chance
                
                    
                        1
                        2
                        3
                    
                
            
            
                wght
                
                    
                        Yes
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        No
                            
                        
                    
                
            
            
                Exservice
                    
                
            
            
                widow
                    
                
            
            go

What is the wrong with the code.i want the jquery for display the result of calculation performed in radiobutton,checkbox,input textbox and combobox.plz help

Comment: what's your input, expected output and actual output? and also please provide your HTML too

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove change event. Just get data from dropdown or radio button. Because when you click button Add, no change event is called here.